# Different uses of registered memory in Debug\Release in CUDA

Tags: c++

I have GeForce 9600 GT with Cuda Compability 1.1 (I know that it is very low), in my kenrel in debug mode I achieved 67% occupancy(128 Threads per Block and use 16 registers), that's enough for me. But in release mode number of used registers has increased to 54 and occupancy was reduced to 17%. So how can I influence the behavior of the compiler?

My Kernel:

```
#define FUN(a, b, c, d, e) d^e^(a&c)^(a&e)^(b&c)^(b&e)^(c&d)^(d&e)^(a&d&e)^(a&c&e)^(a&b&d)^(a&b&c)

__global__ void Cal(u32* FirstTexts, u32* First, u32* SecondTexts, u32* Second, u32* Num){
u32 Thread_ID  = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

u32 Texts_Mem_Loc[32];
u32 Mem_Loc[16];
u32 Num_Loc[16];

memcpy(Num_Loc, Num, sizeof(u32)*16);

//First
memcpy(Texts_Mem_Loc, FirstTexts + Thread_ID * 32, sizeof(u32)*32);
Mem_Loc[ 0] = FUN(Texts_Mem_Loc[31],  Texts_Mem_Loc[26],  Texts_Mem_Loc[20], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 9], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 1] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 0] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[16] ^ Num_Loc[ 0];
Mem_Loc[ 1] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[ 0],  Texts_Mem_Loc[27],  Texts_Mem_Loc[21], Texts_Mem_Loc[10], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 2] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 1] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[17] ^ Num_Loc[ 1];
Mem_Loc[ 2] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[ 1],  Texts_Mem_Loc[28],  Texts_Mem_Loc[22], Texts_Mem_Loc[11], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 3] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 2] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[18] ^ Num_Loc[ 2];
Mem_Loc[ 3] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[ 2],  Texts_Mem_Loc[29],  Texts_Mem_Loc[23], Texts_Mem_Loc[12], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 4] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 3] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[19] ^ Num_Loc[ 3];
Mem_Loc[ 4] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[ 3],  Texts_Mem_Loc[30],  Texts_Mem_Loc[24], Texts_Mem_Loc[13], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 5] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 4] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[20] ^ Num_Loc[ 4];
Mem_Loc[ 5] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[ 4],  Texts_Mem_Loc[31],  Texts_Mem_Loc[25], Texts_Mem_Loc[14], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 6] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 5] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[21] ^ Num_Loc[ 5];
Mem_Loc[ 6] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[ 5],        Mem_Loc[ 0],  Texts_Mem_Loc[26], Texts_Mem_Loc[15], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 7] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 6] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[22] ^ Num_Loc[ 6];
Mem_Loc[ 7] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[ 6],        Mem_Loc[ 1],  Texts_Mem_Loc[27], Texts_Mem_Loc[16], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 8] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 7] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[23] ^ Num_Loc[ 7];
Mem_Loc[ 8] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[ 7],        Mem_Loc[ 2],  Texts_Mem_Loc[28], Texts_Mem_Loc[17], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 9] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 8] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[24] ^ Num_Loc[ 8];
Mem_Loc[ 9] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[ 8],        Mem_Loc[ 3],  Texts_Mem_Loc[29], Texts_Mem_Loc[18], Texts_Mem_Loc[10] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 9] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[25] ^ Num_Loc[ 9];
Mem_Loc[10] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[ 9],        Mem_Loc[ 4],  Texts_Mem_Loc[30], Texts_Mem_Loc[19], Texts_Mem_Loc[11] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[10] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[26] ^ Num_Loc[10];
Mem_Loc[11] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[10],        Mem_Loc[ 5],  Texts_Mem_Loc[31], Texts_Mem_Loc[20], Texts_Mem_Loc[12] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[11] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[27] ^ Num_Loc[11];
Mem_Loc[12] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[11],        Mem_Loc[ 6],        Mem_Loc[ 0], Texts_Mem_Loc[21], Texts_Mem_Loc[13] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[12] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[28] ^ Num_Loc[12];
Mem_Loc[13] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[12],        Mem_Loc[ 7],        Mem_Loc[ 1], Texts_Mem_Loc[22], Texts_Mem_Loc[14] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[13] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[29] ^ Num_Loc[13];
Mem_Loc[14] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[13],        Mem_Loc[ 8],        Mem_Loc[ 2], Texts_Mem_Loc[23], Texts_Mem_Loc[15] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[14] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[30] ^ Num_Loc[14];
Mem_Loc[15] = FUN(      Mem_Loc[14],        Mem_Loc[ 9],        Mem_Loc[ 3], Texts_Mem_Loc[24], Texts_Mem_Loc[16] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[15] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[31] ^ Num_Loc[15];
memcpy(Mem_Loc, First + Thread_ID * 16, sizeof(u32)*16);

//Second
memcpy(Texts_Mem_Loc, SecondTexts + Thread_ID * 32, sizeof(u32)*32);
Mem_Loc[15] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[30],  Texts_Mem_Loc[25],  Texts_Mem_Loc[19], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 8], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 0] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[31] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[15] ^ Num_Loc[15];
Mem_Loc[14] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[29],  Texts_Mem_Loc[24],  Texts_Mem_Loc[18], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 7],       Mem_Loc[15] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[30] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[14] ^ Num_Loc[14];
Mem_Loc[13] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[28],  Texts_Mem_Loc[23],  Texts_Mem_Loc[17], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 6],       Mem_Loc[14] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[29] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[13] ^ Num_Loc[13];
Mem_Loc[12] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[27],  Texts_Mem_Loc[22],  Texts_Mem_Loc[16], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 5],       Mem_Loc[13] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[28] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[12] ^ Num_Loc[12];
Mem_Loc[11] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[26],  Texts_Mem_Loc[21],  Texts_Mem_Loc[15], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 4],       Mem_Loc[12] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[27] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[11] ^ Num_Loc[11];
Mem_Loc[10] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[25],  Texts_Mem_Loc[20],  Texts_Mem_Loc[14], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 3],       Mem_Loc[11] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[26] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[10] ^ Num_Loc[10];
Mem_Loc[ 9] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[24],  Texts_Mem_Loc[19],  Texts_Mem_Loc[13], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 2],       Mem_Loc[10] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[25] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 9] ^ Num_Loc[ 9];
Mem_Loc[ 8] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[23],  Texts_Mem_Loc[18],  Texts_Mem_Loc[12], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 1],       Mem_Loc[ 9] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[24] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 8] ^ Num_Loc[ 8];
Mem_Loc[ 7] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[22],  Texts_Mem_Loc[17],  Texts_Mem_Loc[11], Texts_Mem_Loc[ 0],       Mem_Loc[ 8] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[23] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 7] ^ Num_Loc[ 7];
Mem_Loc[ 6] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[21],  Texts_Mem_Loc[16],  Texts_Mem_Loc[10],       Mem_Loc[15],       Mem_Loc[ 7] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[22] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 6] ^ Num_Loc[ 6];
Mem_Loc[ 5] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[20],  Texts_Mem_Loc[15],  Texts_Mem_Loc[ 9],       Mem_Loc[14],       Mem_Loc[ 6] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[21] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 5] ^ Num_Loc[ 5];
Mem_Loc[ 4] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[19],  Texts_Mem_Loc[14],  Texts_Mem_Loc[ 8],       Mem_Loc[13],       Mem_Loc[ 5] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[20] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 4] ^ Num_Loc[ 4];
Mem_Loc[ 3] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[18],  Texts_Mem_Loc[13],  Texts_Mem_Loc[ 7],       Mem_Loc[12],       Mem_Loc[ 4] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[19] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 3] ^ Num_Loc[ 3];
Mem_Loc[ 2] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[17],  Texts_Mem_Loc[12],  Texts_Mem_Loc[ 6],       Mem_Loc[11],       Mem_Loc[ 3] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[18] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 2] ^ Num_Loc[ 2];
Mem_Loc[ 1] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[16],  Texts_Mem_Loc[11],  Texts_Mem_Loc[ 5],       Mem_Loc[10],       Mem_Loc[ 2] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[17] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 1] ^ Num_Loc[ 1];
Mem_Loc[ 0] = FUN( Texts_Mem_Loc[15],  Texts_Mem_Loc[10],  Texts_Mem_Loc[ 4],       Mem_Loc[ 9],       Mem_Loc[ 1] ) ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[16] ^ Texts_Mem_Loc[ 0] ^ Num_Loc[ 0]; 
memcpy(Mem_Loc, Second + Thread_ID * 16, sizeof(u32)*16); }
```

Comment: In debug mode, I expect your code is also much slower, because it uses more memory locations (because it uses less registers). Since you haven't shown us what `FUN` does, it's hard to say what to expect the compiler to do, but you have a lot of variables and a lot of function calls. That will amount to a lot of code. Many GPU compilers are also very aggressive when it comes to inlining, so you may end up with a very long functon in the release build, which means register allocation is tough. I'm not familiar with this particular compiler (I work with OpenCL for ARM), so can't really help.

Comment: FUN it's simple define funtrion

#define FUN(a, b, c, d, e) d^e^(a&c)^(a&e)^(b&c)^(b&e)^(c&d)^(d&e)^(a&d&e)^(a&c&e)^(a&b&d)^(a&b&c)

Comment: So that's some 30 operations in just one `FUN`. I've not had enough coffee yet, but I'd expect that if you do some logic, you could simplify that expression [you may have to do the a ^ b == a&!b|!a&b transformation first]. Either way, it's a lot of operations, and requires a lot of registers.